# How to Maintain Browser Compatibility

Tags: javascript, browser, compatibility

This is Srinivas, I am working on ASP.Net Technology. I developed on web site, that's works fine in IE but the design is changing from Mozilla, Safari. How to fix the problem.
How to maintain the browser compatibility. I stuck with this problem from last two days. Please provide a solution for fixing this problem. If Possile provie code also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's think about this for a minute... you want us to fix a problem that you haven't even described? What exactly is rendering incorrectly? Can you provide us with the code that is failing? Describe what specifically isn't lining up properly, possibly with some screenshots?

Answer (score 9):

The best way to maintain compatibility is to follow the standards set by W3C. You should also be testing your layout on as many browsers as you can while developing your layout, so you can immediately see what works and what doesn't work. Without seeing any code, I can't make any further suggestions about how to fix the compatibility of your layout.

Comment: +1 for the exact same answer seconds before me.

Comment: Good answer (+1) except not all browsers (especially older ones) follow the standards (IE).

Comment: @Mark: it's easier to follow standards and make exceptions for IE (conditional comments, etc) than it is to design for IE and make exceptions for almost all other browsers.

Comment: @Duncan: True that. Just sayin'. Conforming to W3C specs doesn't guarantee it will render correctly across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-browser compatibility is a touchy subject, but your best bet to alleviate most of your pain is to:

- Use standards-compliant markup.
- Test rigorously.

Ultimately, you'll be making a lot of CSS and Javascript hacks unless you're using a layer that insulates you from the intricacies of each browser's implementations. JQuery is one popular solution, there are many more out there.

Finally, ASP.NET MVC is worlds better than its webforms counterpart for cross-browser development.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, can u please provide any javascript or JQuery for this??

Comment: @raghu: Sure... `<script>$(document).ready(function() { alert("magic code magically fixes everything"); });</script>`

Comment: It's not necessarily true that you will be making loads of CSS and Javascript hacks. I have just built a site and once it looked right in Firefox/Safari/Chrome it took almost no changes for IE.

Comment: @MrMisterMan Agreed, but once things get tricky, they get tricky fast.

Answer (score 1):

Always design for Mozilla/Webkit browsers. When it looks right in standards compliant browsers you can then pander to IE's deficiencies, safe in the knowledge that at least *most* of your code is standards compliant.